# Show separate number with comma in django tempalte

Tags: javascript, django

I have an issue that when the user is typing on text field the number is not separated by a comma

user is typing 500000, it shows 500000 not 500,000

in models

```
so_tien=models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=50)
```

in forms

```
so_tien=forms.IntegerField(label="Số tiền",widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class":"form-control",'onfocusout': 'numberWithCommas()',}),required=False)
```

template file

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="sotien" style="display:none">{{ form.so_tien}}</div>
```

javascript code numberWithCommas in the template file:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
function numberWithCommas(){
  var input = document.getElementById('{{ form.so_tien.id_for_label}}');
  input.value = parseInt(input.value).toLocaleString()
```

}

Thanks for your reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not changing value of your input you're just displaying it try assign new value to value attribute like this

##### Working example

```js
function numberWithCommas(){
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  if(input.value){
    input.value = parseInt(input.value).toLocaleString()
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onfocusout="numberWithCommas()">
```

for django you can do somthing like this
in **forms.py**

```
so_tien=forms.CharField(label="Số tiền",widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'onfocusout': 'numberWithCommas()',}),required=False)
```

inside your **templates**

```
function numberWithCommas(){
  var input = document.getElementById('{{ form.so_tien.id_for_label}}');
  if(input.value){
    input.value = parseInt(input.value).toLocaleString()
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed mycode as you suggested but it doesnt separate number. Then I tried to use console.log(sotien.value), result was NaN. I think this is the issue your code doesnt work. I updated my code

Comment: Hello @DinhTruongAnhPhuong check this line in my code ``var input = document.getElementById('{{ form.so_tien.id_for_label}}');`` and you've written like this ``var input = document.getElementById('sotien');``

Answer (score 0):

Two easy ways

1> you can use [LOCALIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#template-tags) to achieve this with limited control

2>You can create a custom django template tag to achieve this using your own logic like split in reverse and insert comma etc.

--EDIT--

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma

register = template.Library()

def currency(dollars):
    dollars = round(float(dollars), 2)
    return "$%s%s" % (intcomma(int(dollars)), ("%0.2f" % dollars)[-3:])

register.filter('currency', currency)
```

I had previously used this for currency you can modify it as it suits you. in template call {{youvalue|currency}} . Read up on django template tags.

For Javascript:

```
$('.numberfieldclass').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split(",").join(""); // commas
  if (foo.length > 0) {
    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,3}', 'g')).join(",");
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```